# Symfony 4.4.17 logout problem on production server

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I've a weird problem with Symfony 4.4.17 on production, on local is working fine.

I'm using PHP 7.3.21 on dev environment and PHP 7.3.23 on prod environment.

Logout is not working and there's no error in prod.log or in the browser's console.

**security.yaml**:

```
security:
  encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
      algorithm: auto

  # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
  providers:
    app_user_provider:
      entity:
        class: App\Entity\User
        property: email
  firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false
    main:
      anonymous: lazy
      guard:
        authenticators:
          - App\Security\AppAuthenticator
      logout:
        path: app_logout
        target: homepage
      remember_me:
        secret: '%kernel.secret%'
        lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
        path: /
      form_login:
        login_path: homepage
        default_target_path: profile
        use_referer: true
      json_login:
        check_path: signin_ajax

      # activate different ways to authenticate
      # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication
      # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
      # switch_user: true

  # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
  # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
  access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

SecurityController.php:

```
/**
 * @Route("/logout", name="app_logout", methods={"GET"})
 */
public function logoutAction()
{
    throw new \Exception('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall');
}
```

The cookie seems to be fine, this is it's data:

[image: Cookie content]

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure, you didn't forget to clear and warmup cache on prod? If you don't have different dev configuration it should work. How its behave when you access /logout page on prod? Did it show 404 or redirect you to homepage? Are both environments on same machine behind same firewall?

Comment: The behavior is that when I click on logout or type it manually on the URL it redirects me to the homepage but the cookie stills there. I've cleared and warmed up cache on prod several times. There are no firewalls in any environment.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this. Someone wrote an .htaccess rule that conflicts with the logout path. Mystery solved